# how to make table without contents in html?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i need to display no results in table like this:

[image: need this]

But i got only this :

[image: oldone]

my table code is:

```
  {this.state.listAllJobSeekers.length > 0 ?   
        <tbody>
           
            {this.state.listAllJobSeekers.map((JobSeeker,indx)=>
            <tr key={indx}>                       
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                     
            </tr>
            )}
        </tbody> :
        <tbody className="noResult">
           <td>No Results Found</td>
        </tbody>   
         }      

  if data appears it will show, but if there is no data i need to show table with no rows found
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to keep state of the loading state of your request.
As long as that request is loading you can use a different Array to be used to display the rows.

Something like this maybe:

```
{isLoading ?
   new Array(10).fill("").map((item, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
   )):
   this.state.listAllJobSeekers.map((item, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>))}
```

In order to always have a nice fixed height of the table, you would need to add empty rows to your listAllJobSeekers as long as there are less than 10 in there

Answer (score 0):

The *No rows found* text can be placed within the table container with `position: absolute;` and then centered, `relative` to the table.

The empty table can be simulated with a set of empty data (in your case, 10 rows with empty cell data).